# Maven compile “Cannot find symbol” with library from repository but work with explicit import of the jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, compiler-errors, symbols

I have two maven project projectB e projectA, i make INSTALL/DEPLOY/PACKAGE of the projectA and generated all his classes and the compiled jar file.
Now i want to use the projectA like a dependency on projectB so in the pom.xml of projectB i have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.projects</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>   
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

But when i INSTALL/DEPLOY/PACKAGE i end with the famous (found and read many question about that on stackoverflow) error of maven “Cannot find symbol” for all the reference of the code to the projectA.

Now i found out if i use the generated file jar and make a explicit import like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.projects</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>   
    <version>1.1.4</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/projectA.jar</systemPath>    
</dependency>
```

The projectB work fine whithout error.
i'm literaly going nuts for this, anyone can explain me why?

NOTE: in both project i use the apache maven compiler with project source encoding UTF8 e java version 1.8:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <!-- DO NOT include log4j.properties file in your Jar -->
                <excludes>
                    <!--<exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude>-->                       
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Please provide information about the exact Maven command used to compile project A and project B. Also provide Maven pom.xml files for both projects. Also verify if the maven base configurations points to the same local maven repository.

Comment: Please post both pom.xml files from your projects and a screenshot of your project layout in your question so we can actually see what's wrong

Comment: Also do you get the error when running your project or when compiling?

Comment: That is indeed strange. Strange about "Cannot find symbol" - this is not an error I encouter so often with Maven. And why this error and no ClassNotFoundException/NoClassDefError ?
Also, when Maven is not finding a particular dependency, it throws a different error.

Comment: yes...this happens. I would look for common jars..if they are conflicting with each other and versions also.